# Тестирование VK API на локалхост

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, openapi

Как я могу тестировать VK Open API на локалхосте? 
Я подключаю скрипт Open API в хеде, затем инициализирую:

```
VK.init({
    apiId: XXXXXXX,
    onlyWidgets: false,
});

VK.Auth.login((data) => {console.log(data);}, 4);
```

Но возвращается только такой объект, что бы я не делал:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Security Error"}
```

Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что сервер вк не может вернуть ответ туда, куда нужно, потому что не знает куда.

Хотя я гуглил и натыкался на советы о том, что нужно указать локалхост в настройках приложения. Также эта ошибка возникает без причины, но тогда помогает переавторизация на сайте Вк.  Однако в моем случае это, естественно, не помогает.

Comment: В настройках нужно указать сервер, попробуйте

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, какой сервер? Локалхост? Я там что только не пробовал уже: http://joxi.ru/GrqBzD1SQ319ym